# Output format using printf?

Tags: ruby, format, output

I have the following output coming from a Ruby script which I want to format in the following way:

```
tomcat7.0 Build-Date: 20140220-1147
tomcat7.1 Build-Date: 20140220-1147
tomcat7.2 Build-Date: 20140220-1147
tomcat7.3 Build-Date: 20140220-1147
```

I want this in the following format:

```
Name          Build-Date
tomcat7.0    20140220-1147
tomcat7.1    20140220-1147
tomcat7.2    20140220-1147
tomcat7.3    20140220-1147
```

How do i use `printf` or `puts` to format it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex replace as well to have this.

```
input = [
    'tomcat7.0 Build-Date: 20140220-1147',
    'tomcat7.1 Build-Date: 20140220-1147',
    'tomcat7.2 Build-Date: 20140220-1147',
    'tomcat7.3 Build-Date: 20140220-1147'
    ]

input.each{ |x| puts x.gsub(/(.*?)\s+Build-Date:\s+(.*)/, "\\1\t\\2")}
```

Comment: i modify following code in your script `input = myrubyoutput

format = "%-12s %14s\n"
printf( format, "Name", "Build Date" )
input.each{ |x| puts x.gsub(/(.*?)\s+Build-Date:\s+(.*)/, "\\1\t\\2")}
`

Comment: In short your logic works for me :)

Comment: Why split the lines instead of loading the whole file and using my regex?

Answer (score 3):

I'd do using Ruby's **stdlib** [CSV](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) :

```
require 'csv'

str = <<_
tomcat7.0 Build-Date: 20140220-1147
tomcat7.1 Build-Date: 20140220-1147
tomcat7.2 Build-Date: 20140220-1147
tomcat7.3 Build-Date: 20140220-1147
_

ar = []
option = { :write_headers => true, 
           :headers => ['Name','Build-Date'],
           :return_headers => true,
           :col_sep => " "
         }
CSV.parse(str,option) do |row|
  next ar << row.headers.to_csv(:col_sep => " "*9) if row.header_row?
  ar << row.values_at(0,2).to_csv(:col_sep => " "*3)
end

puts ar
# >> Name         Build-Date
# >> tomcat7.0   20140220-1147
# >> tomcat7.1   20140220-1147
# >> tomcat7.2   20140220-1147
# >> tomcat7.3   20140220-1147
```

Comment: A more flexible way :-) +1

Comment: @Abdo Yeah, all did by Ruby. I just arranged them to meet the output. Lolz :-)

Comment: Haha.. Yea, but I mean, using CSV for this purpose is reusable and flexible. You can easily add more columns and handle input changes :-)

Comment: @Abdo Good catch.. I dropped one column( as I am not much bold in regex) `Build-Date:`. Hints `row.values_at(0,2)`.

Comment: Haha.. Still easier to change than my `i % 3 == 1`

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this? (I know I'm not using printf =) )

```
str = %(tomcat7.0 Build-Date: 20140220-1147
tomcat7.1 Build-Date: 20140220-1147
tomcat7.2 Build-Date: 20140220-1147
tomcat7.3 Build-Date: 20140220-1147)

LEFT_JUST = 15

puts "%s%s" % ['Name'.ljust(LEFT_JUST), "Build-Date"]
str.scan(/\S+(?=.)/).reject.with_index { |e, i| 
 i % 3 == 1 }.each_slice(2) { |l,r| puts "#{l.ljust(LEFT_JUST)} #{r}" }
```

Outputs:

```
Name           Build-Date
tomcat7.0       20140220-1147
tomcat7.1       20140220-1147
tomcat7.2       20140220-1147
tomcat7.3       20140220-1147
```

**Edit**: A better regex and code would be the following:

```
LEFT_JUST = 15
str.scan(/(?<first>\S+)\s(\S+)\s(?<third>\S+)\n*/).each { |l,r| 
  puts "#{l.ljust(LEFT_JUST)} #{r}" 
}
```

Comment: You are great.. +1.. I am not much mature to understand this code. :-)

Comment: You mean the regexp? I just used http://rubular.com to figure out the pattern :-)

Comment: Yes.. regexp. I am not comfortable with it. still learning from internet. :(

Comment: Neither am I... I'm trying to answer such questions to improve my regexp skills :-)

Comment: One suggestion, you can use [`captures`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/MatchData.html#method-i-captures) method also. Just split the string on `"\n"`. take each string and pass it through regex, then call the method `#captures`, and the result keep pushing into an array. Once all string captures will be done let me know please. Then I will tell you the next.

Comment: The issue with splitting is that it already goes through the string once, which is not efficient. Using regexes on every single split defeats the purpose of using 1 regex in the first place :-) ... There's definitely a way to improve my regex above to avoid the `reject` and `each_slice` .. I'll look for improvements :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47997/discussion-between-arup-rakshit-and-abdo)

Comment: @ArupRakshit found a regexp that does a better job =)

Comment: That's a cool.. I knew you are a Rubyist :-)

Comment: @ArupRakshit haha.. Working on it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to do it using a [`String.%`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-25) (format):

```
FORMAT = "%-9s\t%s"
TEXT_FILE_CONTENT = [
  'tomcat7.0 Build-Date: 20140220-1147',
  'tomcat7.1 Build-Date: 20140220-1147',
  'tomcat7.2 Build-Date: 20140220-1147',
  'tomcat7.3 Build-Date: 20140220-1147',
]

puts FORMAT % %w[Name Build-Date]
puts TEXT_FILE_CONTENT.map{ |l| FORMAT % /^(\S+).+?(\S+)$/.match(l).captures }
```

Which outputs:

```
Name       Build-Date
tomcat7.0  20140220-1147
tomcat7.1  20140220-1147
tomcat7.2  20140220-1147
tomcat7.3  20140220-1147
```

You could similarly do it like:

```
TEXT_FILE_CONTENT.each{ |l| puts FORMAT % /^(\S+).+?(\S+)$/.match(l).captures }
```

`%` will expect an array, because there are two placeholders in the format. Here's where the array comes from:

```
/^(\S+).+?(\S+)$/.match('tomcat7.3 Build-Date: 20140220-1147').captures
# => ["tomcat7.3", "20140220-1147"]
```

Of, if you want to do it as a pipe, save this as "s1.rb":

```
TEXT_FILE_CONTENT = [
  'tomcat7.0 Build-Date: 20140220-1147',
  'tomcat7.1 Build-Date: 20140220-1147',
  'tomcat7.2 Build-Date: 20140220-1147',
  'tomcat7.3 Build-Date: 20140220-1147',
]

puts TEXT_FILE_CONTENT
```

And this as "s2.rb":

```
FORMAT = "%-9s\t%s"
puts FORMAT % %w[Name Build-Date]

ARGF.each{ |l| puts FORMAT % /^(\S+).+?(\S+)$/.match(l).captures }
```

Then run them as:

```
ruby s1.rb | ruby s2.rb
```

And you should see something like:

```
Name      Build-Date
tomcat7.0 20140220-1147
tomcat7.1 20140220-1147
tomcat7.2 20140220-1147
tomcat7.3 20140220-1147
```

The advantage to the later is you're working with small specialized scripts which do only one thing. Combining them via a pipe ("`|`") is the *nix way of building big apps from small ones.

Comment: Can you give me the link of `|` pipe in the doc?

Comment: ok I got [`Using Pipe Characters`](http://ruby.about.com/od/tutorials/a/commandline_3.htm) it.